# MariaDB clone running DB and setup master-master replication

Tags: mariadb, database-replication, high-availability

I need to setup master-master replication MariaDB cluster. Now I got a single MariaDB server and database is too big to just stop first node, transfer a copy to second node and launch both in master-master replication mode. I can only restart DB for applying config changes. Is there any way to create second node without stopping the first one for a long period of time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Mariabackup can take an online copy of your data to seed the replica.

Use the [--slave-info](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariabackup-options/#-slave-info) option for Mariabackup to create a [xtrabackup_slave_info](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/files-created-by-mariabackup/#xtrabackup_slave_info) file with the [CHANGE MASTER TO](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/change-master-to/) position to continue to replicate from.

Don't forget to use --prepare before starting the server.

ref: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-up-a-replica-with-mariabackup/

Comment: As far as I undestood this is all about master-slave replication. I need master-master. I guess I need Galera Cluster setup. If I'll make a dump of running DB, then transfer it to a second node while first one is still running and then restart both nodes with wsrep configured will the first node populate missing data on the second one?

Comment: Because "master-master" and "MariaDB cluster" are too overloaded terms I missed the implied galera. [wsrep_sst_method=mariabackup](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/galera-cluster-system-variables/#wsrep_sst_method) or "mysqldump". Note [Minimal Cluster Size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/introduction-to-state-snapshot-transfers-ssts/#minimal-cluster-size)